# Rails Console printing a message and query taking too much time to load

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Every time when I load my **rails** server and over the console it shows:

```
 (522.5ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
```

[image]
Actually, it is taking about 500 milliseconds to load and, sometimes, it takes up to 800 milliseconds, which is not good for my app.

- What does this message mean?
- How I can resolve it?

Please help and suggest a correct way to do.

Comment: i very very much doubt that setting a few session variables are costing 500-800 ms to execute on your MySQL server iám pretty sure you are also timing making the MySQL connection there.. On this one it's is almost [instant](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w5C45hYEvE2YVKer38LFyt/0)

Comment: These sessions variables are there to use the charset utf8 your session.. Force the session into using stict SQL meaning the insert/updates need to use the correct datatypes, MySQL will error when a value is to large without truncating the value.. With other words important stuff..

Comment: Also looking into the screenshot iám pretty sure the `522.5ms` is the total time of executng the http request and server processing on the `/table` url. .

Comment: How can I resolve it?

Comment: Before you try to resolve execute the query on MySQL with a SQL IDE to time it there.. If the result are the same your MySQL is not running correctly and a restart might be required.. Like i said those session variables should execute in less then 20-30 ms..

Comment: I saw this in my dev environment after being away 1–2 hours and then loading a page from my app. rack-mini-profiler showed the SQL transaction duration itself was 626 ms, while "action: show" before that took 1152 ms (normally would be <= 20 ms). I re-executed the SQL query in my client and it took 30 ms. My guess is the Rails server had disconnected from the database server and needed to reconnect and run that query after doing so, but I'd also like a clear explanation. (This was with Rails 6.1, local MariaDB server).